# SharePoint 2010 - How to replace the default rich text editor used for multi-line fields in lists with TinyMCE?

Tags: sharepoint, tinymce

does anybody have any experience with replacing the default rich text editor for multiline fields in SharePoint 2010 lists with TinyMCE?

There a few links around for doing that in SP 2007, but i am unable to get them work - http://joshmccarty.com/2011/06/use-tinymce-as-the-rich-text-editor-in-sharepoint-forms/comment-page-1/#comment-1015

please also CC me at jiri@jiripik.com.

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe it’s better to write your own [Custom field type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms446361.aspx), inherited it from [SPFieldMultiLineText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfieldmultilinetext.aspx) and override property [FieldRenderingControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfield.fieldrenderingcontrol.aspx) and return control which use TinyMCE?

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that in SP2010, the RTE is located in the ribbon by default. YOu can still have an editor shown in the field itself (see [this](http://blog.mastykarz.nl/rich-text-editor-control-sharepoint-2010/) for more info), but my question is: why would you want to do this, as this would break the user experience, seeing as everything else is in the ribbon?

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I created a simple [bookmarklet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet) to swizzle in TinyMCE into a Sharepoint page.

You'll need to find somewhere to host TinyMCE.  Most MacOS X boxes have a local webserver (if you enable Web Sharing) whose document root is in `/Library/WebServer/Documents`.

The bookmarklet then is:

```
    javascript:(function() {
       h = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
       scriptT = document.createElement("script");
       scriptT.src = "http://localhost/js/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js";
       scriptT.type = "text/javascript";
       scriptT.onload = function(){
          tinyMCE.init({mode: "textareas", theme:"advanced",
             theme_advanced_toolbar_location:"top"});
       };
       h.appendChild(scriptT);
    })()
```

On Chrome, I was able to just copy and paste the above into a new bookmark and Chrome took care of the line ends etc.

It's not a perfect solution by any means, but it certainly makes my life easier.  Notable issues: popups don't work, for example, so you can't enter in links or HTML.